# Digital isolator OOK and edge-based encoding supply current consumption

Tags: digital-logic, modulation, digital-isolator

I am reading this article [the use of robust digital isolators in the harsh environments of electric motor drives](https://www.analog.com/jp/technical-articles/the-use-of-robust-digital-isolators-in-the-harsh-environments.html)
and it says pulse encoding uses more supply current at higher data rates than 10 Mbps than OOK, anybody knows the explanation why?

Answer (score 0):

For my answer, I am borrowing the diagrams from the Texas Instruments' [*Application Note **Digital Isolator Design Guide***](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla284d/slla284d.pdf?ts=1642307579911).

[image: Fig1-1]

**Figure 1-1 Conceptual Block Diagram of Edge-Based Architecture**, App Note SLLA284D, page 3

[image: Fig1-2-3]

**Figure 1-2. Conceptual Block Diagram of On-Off Keying (OOK) Architecture**, AppNote SLLA284D, page 4

Let us compare the signal powers in edge-based communication (\$P_{edge}\$) and in OOK (\$P_{OOK}\$) designs required to provide equivalent SNR figures.

Let \$N_0\$ is a noise spectral density in our solution. A frequency range required for a detection of peak signals is on the order of \$1/τ_{peak}\$. SNR for edge-based communication is on the order of
$$ 
P_{edge}/(N_0/τ_{peak})
$$
When detecting the OOK signal, we can limit a frequency range of the signal conditioning circuitry to a value of \$f_{osc}/n\$, \$f_{osc}\$ is a frequency of the OOK internal oscillator id Figure 1-2, \$n\$ is the number of clock periods per on-keyed pulse in Figure 1-3. SNR is
$$
P_{OOK}/(N_0·(f_{osc}/n))
$$
For these SNRs to be compatible, we need this ratio to hold
$$
P_{edge}/P_{OOK} \sim (N_0/τ_{peak})/(N_0·(f_{osc}/n)) = n/(f_{osc}·τ_{peak}) = T_{data}/τ_{peak}
$$
\$T_{data}\ = n/f_{osc}\$ is the interval between data line signal's rises/falls; effectively, it cannot be less than the inverse of a data rate. \$τ_{peak}\$ is an RC constant of the isolation barrier capacitors and the pullup resistors at the RX comparator inputs. For the data signal to effectively cross the isolation barrier **in the high-frequency channel (not PWM channel!)**, this constant should be smaller than \$T_{data}\$ (see Figure 1-1). Therefore, the signal power \$P_{edge}\$ in an edge-based communication solution should be greater than the signal power \$P_{OOK}\$ in an OOK based solution under assumptions made in the above derivation.

For precise comparison, one needs the details of both solutions. There is no public data on an internal spread spectrum oscillator
clock to generate OOK signaling ([TI's Isolation forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/isolation-group/isolation/f/isolation-forum/663246/few-question-on-digital-isolators) states it explicitly:
`We generally don't disclose the frequency of the spread-spectrum block on the public forum. I'll contact you offline and we can continue the discussion there`), but it certainly can be made high enough to provide the power efficiency advantage of the OOK based architecture at a data rate of, say, 10 MHz and above.

To delve deeper, pay attention to the **Table 3-1. Digital Isolator Families and Isolated Functions** (page 9) of [*Application Note **Digital Isolator Design Guide***](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla284d/slla284d.pdf?ts=1642307579911). The CMTI (Common Mode Transient Immunity) column provides additional, albeit indirect, insight into your question: see data in **Timing Performance**, **CMTI**, and **Power per Channel** columns of the products listed.